# Profile page throwing HTTP 500 errors

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on my .Net application and the following page generates a page for the user's profile

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Profile for user: <%= _profile.Username %></h1>
            <h2>Purchases</h2>
            <% foreach (var purchase in _purchases) { %>
                <h3><%= purchase.Id %>: <%= purchase.Quantity %> items at $<%= Math.Round(purchase.Price / 100.0) %>.</h3>            
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CS code behind it -

```
public partial class profile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected Profile _profile;
    protected List<Purchase> _purchases;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileHelper.IncrementActiveRequests();
        try
        {
            var username = Context.Request.QueryString["username"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Missing required parameter: username");
            } 
            else 
            {
                _profile = ProfileHelper.GetProfile(username);

                // Extract the purchases
                _purchases = _profile.Purchases;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ProfileHelper.DecrementActiveRequests();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the page is constantly throwing HTTP 500 error off of the GET username request. Is there a way I can catch this error?

Comment: Don't use `double` for financial calculations. You'll end up in rounding-hell. This is specifically why the `decimal` type exists in C#.

Comment: I can fix this but I don't believe thats the issue @spender

Comment: Look in the Windows event logs (the Application log) to find the actual error message.

Comment: I've added the CS code to bring in further insight

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is to get the error description. I'll assume that you are on a production environment, because usually in development the errors show clearly. You can override the OnError method of the page to get the exact error. Also handling the page_error event is a possible way.
Otherwise you can get it on the Application_error of the global.asax